# Install ardrone_autonomy on ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone !

Do you know how to install the package ardrone_autonomy on ROS kinetic  (if it's possible) ?

Thank you for your help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254450/install-ardrone_autonomy-on-ros-kinetic/) by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2017-02-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on 2017-02-11**:
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS Xenial

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:
And what have you tried yourself that didn't work?

**Comment by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on 2017-02-12**:
I tried to install the package from the indigo branch, before that I ran sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy

**Comment by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on 2017-02-12**:
The catkin_make didn't work

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:
But the `apt-get` did?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:
Are you on an ARM platform by any chance?

**Comment by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on 2017-02-12**:
The apt-get command works well ans i'm using Intel processor

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:
So .. the package would then be installed, would it not?

After having `source`d `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, it should be available.

What is the output of `rospack find ardrone_autonomy`?

**Comment by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on 2017-02-12**:
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ardrone_autonomy

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-12**:
That would seem to indicate that the package is installed.

At this point I'm slightly confused about your question.

**Comment by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on 2017-02-12**:
but in this package there's no CMakeList.txt

**Comment by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on 2017-02-12**:
I confused myself xD
I was trying to use an indigo package called ardrone_autonomy from this link : https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy , I was wrong

**Comment by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on 2017-02-12**:
Finally I downloaded the package with apt-get and this package is located at : /opt/ros/kinetic/share/ardrone_autonomy. I copied/pasted it in catkin_ws/src and I would like to run catkin_make but there's no CMakeList

**Comment by [jorge.vargas](https://answers.ros.org/users/22977/jorge.vargas/) on 2017-04-05**:
I get E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy when I use   sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-ardrone-autonomy, help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That github link and the package you install using `apt-get` are one and the same.

If you install something using `apt-get`, you **don't** need to build it with `catkin_make` anymore.

What would be the point of distributing binaries otherwise?

---

Edit:

> Ahhhh I thought they were different because in the link the ROS version is indigo and mine is kinetic. Thx !!

The Kinetic version is released from the `indigo-devel` branch. See [wiki/ardrone_autonomy](http://wiki.ros.org/ardrone_autonomy).

If you ever do need to build a package from source, what you did is not the way to go about it. See #q252478 for a general description of the process.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matt27110](https://answers.ros.org/users/29236/matt27110/) on 2017-02-12**:
Ahhhh
I thought they were different because in the link the ROS version is indigo and mine is kinetic.
Thx !!